# how to read the JSON file in java as key value pair for below given JSON?

Tags: java

```
{
    "XML": {
        "version": 1.0,
        "encoding": "UTF-8"
    },
    "Comment": "ABC EFG Json",
    "pCt": {
        "pCHead": {
            "Date": "9999-12-31",
            "ID ": "12345 ",
            "Type": "ABC",
            "prtList": [{
                "cCType": "B",
                "cReason": "",
                "oInd": 10,
            }],
            "pNet": [{
                "seType": "3",
                "eDate": "2016-10-01",
                "exDate": "9999-12-31",


            }]
        }
    }
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    System.out.println("hii");
    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("D:\\TestJson.txt"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        Object pCt =  jsonObject.get("pCt");
        String author = (String) jsonObject.get("pCHead");
        JSONArray companyList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("prtList");

        System.out.println("Name: " + pCt);
        System.out.println("\nCompany List:"+author);
        System.out.println("\nCompany List:");
        Iterator<String> iterator = companyList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: correct the formatting and add more details

Answer (score 0):

Your parsing is more or less correct depending on JSON that I would not read.
Only mistake is that companyList is JSONArray and it's elements are of Object type. You need to externally cast it to JSONObject and then get your model out of it.

```
//lombok
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Company {
    String cCType;
    String cReason;
    String oInd;
}

//in your main
for(Object o : companyList) {
    JSONObject companyJson = (JSONObject) o;
    Company company = Company.Builder
       .anCompany()
       .withCCType(companyJson.get("cCType"))
       .withCReason(companyJson.get("cReaeson"))
       .withOInd(companyJson.get("oInd"))
       .build();
//do whatever you like with data
}
```